# Get same categories as woocommerce breadcrumbs have

Tags: woocommerce

I have multiple categories apllied to product, but woocommerce breadcrumbs choose only one line to show. I want to follow his line to show related products based on category shown in breadcrumbs.
Woocommerce `breadcrumb.php` file has

```
foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {
}
```

I want to know from where `$breadcrumb` goes to get same `$crumb`.

Answer (score 0):

*This solution for those who has product in several categories.*

I found `wc_get_product_terms()`, this is how breadcrumbs created. So if you want to display related products based on category shown in breadcrumbs, you can do similar to this:

```
$term = wc_get_product_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat', array('orderby' => 'parent', 'order' => 'DESC'));
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $term[0]->term_id
                ),
            )
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
```

But I found a better way with **`yoast seo`** plugin:

```
$primary_term_product_id = yoast_get_primary_term_id('product_cat');
```

and then use `$primary_term_product_id` instead of `$term[0]->term_id`.

*This solution for those who has product in several categories.*